# align h1 before and after background

Tags: html, css

I have image before and after h1.

However, I need to position it as following:

- `h1` text should be in the center
- `h1` before image should start at the left side of container
- `h1` after image should end at the right side of container

I cannot get all of them. For example, I can center h1 text, but then h1 before and h1 after images are not aligned correctly. Here is jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/wK8ve/

Also Html and css here:

CSS:

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5d5d5d;
    margin: 0 0 32px 0;        
}

h1:before {
    text-align: left;
    background-image: url('http://modeles-de-lettres.org/test/images/h_ltr.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;     
    background-position: center left;   
    padding: 0 352px 0 0;
    content: "\00a0";
}

h1:after {
    background-image: url('http://modeles-de-lettres.org/test/images/h_rtl.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    background-position: center right;
    padding: 0 180px;
    content: "\00a0";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

And here is live example: http://modeles-de-lettres.org/test/index.php?p=about_us

Answer (score 1):

use `float`.

In your before and after sections you will want

http://jsfiddle.net/wK8ve/1/

```
h1:before {
    text-align: left;
    background-image: url('http://modeles-de-lettres.org/test/images/h_ltr.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;     
    background-position: center left;   
    padding: 0 352px 0 0;
    content: "\00a0";
}

h1:after {
    float: right;
    background-image: url('http://modeles-de-lettres.org/test/images/h_rtl.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    background-position: center right;
    padding: 0 180px;
    content: "\00a0";
}
```

I'm assuming this is what you want anyway, if not clarify.

Comment: `h1:before` and `h1:after` add to the text node, which has `display: inline-block`. This means, the image will be displayed in the space it of "\00a0Test\00a0" (or in a slightly larger space if you use padding). You could change `display` to `block` with or without a custom width and/or a margin, but this will not work properly (they will be displayed above and below the content of h1). `float` will probably work better as @echolocation already stated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want. I used `img` instead of `:before` and `:after`

http://jsfiddle.net/wK8ve/2/